# How to Delete a Row from multiply tables in sql?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

so i have to tables that have a relation between them - relation type: one to many.
and i thought that the following query:

```
DELETE Orderstbl.*, ItemsInOrdertbl.*
FROM Orderstbl INNER JOIN ItemsInOrdertbl ON Orderstbl.OrderID = ItemsInOrdertbl.OrderId
WHERE (((Orderstbl.OrderID)=26));
```

will delete all the rows in both tables that contain the OrderID = 26
but to my surprise it filled the following error :

```
could not delete from specified tables
```

tried to find an answer on google , didnt help much thanks in advance :D

Comment: use transaction to wrap deletion from more than one table as separate statements, otherwise use cascade but you need to mess with table relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a relationship that includes `CASCADE DELETE`, then when you delete from one it will delete from the other

from [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304466):

> If you select the Cascade Delete Related Records check box when you
>   define a relationship, any time that you delete records in the primary
>   table, Microsoft Access automatically deletes related records in the
>   related table. For example, if you delete a customer record from the
>   Customers table, all the customer's orders are automatically deleted
>   from the Orders table (this includes records in the Order Details
>   table related to the Orders records). When you delete records from a
>   form or datasheet with the Cascade Delete Related Records check box
>   selected, Microsoft Access warns you that related records may also be
>   deleted. However, when you delete records using a delete query,
>   Microsoft Access automatically deletes the records in related tables
>   without displaying a warning.

Using the `CASCADE DELETE` is a simple and clean way to make sure the correct records are removed from both tables.

Here is another article discussing CASCADE DELETE with MS-Access.

[Delete one or more records from an Access database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/delete-one-or-more-records-from-an-access-database-HA001173951.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a foreign key set between columns in two tables, you have to be sure to delete the child column first, and then the master. The proper way to do this is to set a constraint upon deletion of the master, such as UPDATE or DELETE. The constraint takes care of the foreign key relations, so you never wind up with orphan rows all over the place.

To create the constraints in MySQL (for example)...

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

The other option is to do it programmatically, deleting the row in child tables first, and then the master.